# Class generation for OPC-UA Information Model with MILO client

Tags: code-generation, opc-ua, milo

I try read data from an OPC-UA server that uses an Information Model (Euromap 77). I tried it using the Prosys SDK with Java Objects generated from the NodeSet.xml.
Now I want to use the Milo SDK.
Is there a generation tool for Java classes for Milo too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no publicly available code generation tool for Milo.

It's being developed privately and I'm not sure on what terms it will be made available in the future.

If that's something you need immediately then I'd suggest continuing to use the Prosys SDK for now.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it will be available?